# Operating on a large string never completes MSSQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, bigdata, ssms

I have been downloading a large file daily. Until now, my .NET program has processed it in a background thread; However, we are occasionally having issues where someone restarts prior to completion, and it has to start over again.

I am trying to migrate it into SQL Server. I can dump the entire file as a varchar(max) very quickly. The idea is to trigger the long running operation in SQL Server once the line is written.

However, It never comes back. My guess is eventually it would, as my splitting function is well tested and I've used it for years, but I have waited as long as 7 minutes, even if I abstract it from my loop and only operate on the first row. I never get the first row back.

There must be an alternative way to operate on big data that won't take 10 minutes per line in something that has hundreds-thousands of lines.

I looked into STRING_SPLIT, but unfortunately we're on 2012 and it's not available.

My splitting function (original code is from here somewhere. It works perfectly on smaller varchars).

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitReturnVarchar](
@sInputList VARCHAR(max) -- List of delimited items
, @sDelimiter VARCHAR(10) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (rowNum int identity,item VARCHAR(max))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(max)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT
    @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX( @sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
    @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter, @sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
 RETURN
END
```

Again, this works fine on small strings. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitReturnVarchar('12#45','#')
```

returns

```
  rowNum    item
   1         12
   2         45
```

However, LEN(@String) for this varchar is 2,379,052.
I'm splitting on char(10), and eventually need to split on comma - but I can't even get the char(10) split to return.

For example:

```
DECLARE @YesterdayFullStringFut varchar(max) = (SELECT DataString 
        FROM CMESettleStaging 
        WHERE [Date] = CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) AS date) 
        AND DataType = 'Future')

SELECT LEN(@YesterdayFullStringFut) --2379052

DECLARE @ProcessLine varchar(max) = (SELECT item 
        FROM dbo.fnSplitReturnVarchar(@YesterdayFullStringFut,char(10)) 
        WHERE rowNum = 2) --never returns, 8:30 longest wait - too long.
SELECT @ProcessLine
```

How do I do this with big data? It took a long time in .NET, but *not anywhere* near this long.

Comment: Use SSIS package and a SQL job to import the file.  Or worst case use c# SQL is not well suited to splitting strings

Comment: Build one of these string splitters instead: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: @Brad I already told the owner we may want a separate program or service to handle this. Depending on these comments/answers we very may well go that route.

Comment: @Xedni ty I will look into it.

Comment: Yeah that splitter is going to cripple your server on large strings. My favorite is the one by Jeff Moden in the link above from @Xedni. There are some other great alternatives here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Your best bet for performance would be to use a CLR function -- but once you go that route, as long as external processing is an option, you may as well use that instead. Most string splitters out there are intended to handle simple lists, not 2 MB large monstrosities.

Comment: Even if you get this string split working, I would go that route anyway in the end.  It will take a HUGE load off your SQL server using that large of data and splitting all in memory.  The SSIS package is much better suited to this, and for a simple import of a file is easy to create the package

Comment: We're going with a Service to abstract it from our main application. That way the service runs even if they shut the main suite down. We have remote desktop that needs ctrl-alt-delete functionality anyway, and my research thus far says that needs a service to work - so we were going to get here eventually anyway. Thanks for all of the advice guys - ya'll really helped.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to get very good performance using 2016 built-in STRING_SPLIT. We are using 2012 locally, but already have an Azure set up to 140 compat (2017), which includes STRING_SPLIT. So, I wrote the below, and we went from hours of processing (fastest was 82 minutes in .NET), to approximately 45 seconds, fully in SQL.

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE([1] varchar(50), [2] varchar(50), [3] varchar(50), [4] varchar(50), [5] varchar(50),[6] varchar(250), [7] varchar(50), [8] varchar(50), [9] varchar(50), [10] varchar(50),
                       [11] varchar(50), [12] varchar(50), [13] varchar(50), [14] varchar(50), [15] varchar(50),[16] varchar(50), [17] varchar(50), [18] varchar(50), [19] varchar(50), [20] varchar(50),
                       [21] varchar(50), [22] varchar(50))
--@Results to perm table.
DECLARE @Temp TABLE ([value] varchar(max))
INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(@data,char(10))

DECLARE @innerData varchar(100)
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT [value] FROM @Temp

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur
INTO @innerData;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Results
    SELECT p2.[1],p2.[2],p2.[3],p2.[4],p2.[5],p2.[6],p2.[7],p2.[8],p2.[9],p2.[10],
           p2.[11],p2.[12],p2.[13],p2.[14],p2.[15],p2.[16],p2.[17],p2.[18],p2.[19],p2.[20],
           p2.[21],p2.[22]
    FROM(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order BY @innerData) AS rowNum,* FROM STRING_SPLIT(@innerData,',')         
    ) p
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([value])
        FOR rowNum IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
                       [11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],
                       [21],[22])
    ) p2
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @innerData;
END
SELECT * FROM @Results
```

This processed 24,039 rows in 47 seconds, which is a significant improvement, and good result for us.